# Add additional properties to json array member schema

Tags: jsonschema

I'm trying to create 2 separate schemas for some json files which serve as scripts.
One schema should contain all commands possible, while another one should only contain a subset of commands.

My thinking was I create minimal schema first:

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "$schema": {},
        "commands": {
            "type": "array",
            "items":
            {
                "title": "One step of the migration",
                "type": "object",
                "minProperties": 1,
                "maxProperties": 1,

                "properties": {
                    "simple_command_1": {"type": "object"},
                    "simple_command_2": {"type": "object"},
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which would validate json files like this:

```json
{
    "$schema": "../../migration_schema_v1.json",
    "commands": [
        {"simple_command_1": {}},
        {"simple_command_1": {}},
        {"simple_command_2": {}},
        {"simple_command_2": {}},
    ]
```

I'm trying to avoid using the word `extend` but... I want to be able to create a second schema that has every command the first one has and an additional `advanced_command_3`. So I created this:

```json
    "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
    "$ref": "/migration_schema_v1.json#/",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "foo": {
            "type": "object",
            "title": "this does work"
        },
        "commands": {
            "items":
            {
                "properties": {
                    "advanced_command_3": {"type": "object"}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm able to refer this second schema, and it does inherit everything from the first one, but I'm not really able to add any properties (commands)

I was however able to add additional properties in the root, next to "commands". See "foo" property.

Using `allOf[]` or `$ref` in the sub-property doesn't seem to make a difference.

Am I getting this all wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would actually break this into three schemas.  The first contains the primary definition for your data, including all of the valid commands.

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "$id": "https://example.com/definitions",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "$schema": {},
    "commands": {
      "type": "array",
      "items":
      {
        "title": "One step of the migration",
        "type": "object",
        "minProperties": 1,
        "maxProperties": 1,

        "properties": {
          "simple_command_1": {"type": "object"},
          "simple_command_2": {"type": "object"},
          "advanced_command_3": {"type": "object"}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The other two are your simple and advanced schemas.  They work by defining that only the possibilities of the commands you want are *required* then referencing back to the definition schema to get the rest of the requirements.

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "$id": "https://example.com/simple",
  "$ref": "definitions",
  "properties": {
    "commands": {
      "items": {
        "anyOf": [
          { "required": ["simple_command_1"] },
          { "required": ["simple_command_2"] }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}

{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "$id": "https://example.com/advanced",
  "$ref": "definitions",
  "properties": {
    "commands": {
      "items": {
        "anyOf": [
          { "required": ["simple_command_1"] },
          { "required": ["simple_command_2"] },
          { "required": ["advanced_command_3"] }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I think this setup contains minimal repetition.

---

At this point you *might* be able to get away with what you're wanting to do with the `extends` thing.  You'd have to extract the commands requirements in the simple schema into a `$defs` keyword and reference them from the advanced schema.

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "$id": "https://example.com/simple",
  "$defs": {
    "simpleCommands": {
      "anyOf": [
        { "required": ["simple_command_1"] },
        { "required": ["simple_command_2"] }
      ]
    }
  },
  "$ref": "definitions",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "commands": {
      "items": { "$ref": "#/$defs/simpleCommands" }
    }
  }
}

{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "$id": "https://example.com/advanced",
  "$ref": "definitions",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "commands": {
      "items": {
        "anyOf": [
          { "$ref" : "simple#/$defs/simpleCommands" },
          { "required": ["advanced_command_3"] }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I haven't tested this though.

Comment: Sounds like a neat pattern, quite different from others I tried. Will give it a go tomorrow. I gave splitting in 3 some thought but thought I am missing more than just overall structure  I think my intuition about how object arrays work is wrong